# Is there a better library for drawing vector graphics in Python than Cairo?

Tags: python, vector-graphics, cairo, pycairo

...Not that I have anything against Cairo -- I love it in fact.  It's just terribly difficult to install the Python bindings, especially on a Mac (see all the SO questions about installing pycairo on OS X).  Are there better alternatives?

**Edit:**

For a little more context, I'm creating a web service that I would like to be simple to deploy, ideally using standard installation channels; not being able to simply use `pip` or `easy_install` introduces complexity into the deployment process on many deployment platforms.   Additionally, I'd like it to be easy for anyone to set up a virtual environment and do development on the application on their local machine.  Again, ease of installation is an important point here.

Comment: ...define "better"?  By what criteria are you judging?

Comment: @André: Apparently, by ease of installation on a Mac.

Comment: @AndréCaron good point; I provided a little more context above.

Comment: I love cairo for desktop gui apps, but for online stuff I am considering the use of HTML5 Canvas element. Well, just an idea ;o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kiva, part on [Enable](http://github.com/enthought/enable), is a library which abstracts the vector renderer. It supports cairo, Agg, and several other renderers, though Agg is the default. It works on Linux, OS X and Windows.

Comment: oops, I forgot, on OS X, the default is the native Quartz renderer.

Comment: Why don’t you update your answer by editing it instead of making an addendum comment?

Answer (score 4):

cairocffi installs cleanly with pip/virtualenv and provides the same API as pycairo.
http://packages.python.org/cairocffi/